# Contador que sume de 2 en 2

Tags: java

Es mi primer post en este foro, estoy empezando a programar, y me ha surgido esta duda en un ejercicio.
Tengo que hallar la suma de los 20 números siguientes a un número introducido por teclado, y la suma de los 20 números pares siguientes. Este es mi código:

```
if(numero%2==0){
     boolean par=true;
  }else{
     boolean par=false;
  }

  if(par==true){

     for(int i=numero, j=numero+40;i<=j;i+2){   //Este i+2 es lo que tengo mal
        total_par=total_par+i;
     }
  }else{

     for(int i=numero+1,j=numero+40;i<=j;i+2){  //Aquí también
        total_par=total_par+i;
     }
  }
```

Gracias

Comment: Y ¿cual es el problema específicamente?

Comment: No se como hacer un contador que me avance dos números en vez de uno, como haria con i++.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque es un ejercicio del colegio

Comment: No comparto el motivo de cierre de Alberto. El usuario no está pidiendo que le resolvamos el problema dándole un código (es más, tampoco podemos inferir que sea ejercicio de colegio), está pidiendo ayuda con un ejercicio que parece él ha hecho y que no le funciona como lo espera.

Comment: `i` **`+=`** `2`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`i+2` debería cambiarse a

```
i = i + 2
```

o

```
i += 2
```

Escoge el que prefieres.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no había caído.

Comment: @MigHc Considera aceptar la respuesta si ha resuelto tu problema. Para ello, tienes un tick en el lado izquierdo de la respuesta, lo marcas como verde y listo :) De esta manera, usuarios que vengan a ver tu pregunta en el futuro, podrán ver de una manera mucho más clara cual ha sido la solución al problema. Gracias!

Comment: Lo había intentado dar, pero había que esperar 10 mins y se me ha ido pasando. Ya está aceptado, gracias por recordarlo

Comment: @MigHc De nada. Hay a mucha gente que se le olvida por esta misma razón. Otra mucha que lo desconocen totalmente. Simplemente intento ayudar a hacer una comunidad mejor :)

Answer (score 3):

También puedes utilizar una fórmula:

```
int total;
if (num % 2 == 0) {
    // k + k + 2 + k + 4 + k + 6 + ... + k + 40
    // k + 20k + 2 + 4 + 6 + ... + 40
    // k + 20k + 20 * (20 + 1)
    // 21k + 420
    total = 21 * num + 420;
} else {
    // k + k + 1 + k + 3 + k + 5 + ... + k + 39
    // k + 20k + 1 + 3 + 5 + ... + 39
    // k + 20k + 20 * 20
    // 21k + 400
    total = 21 * num + 400;
}
System.out.println(total);
```

- Si `num = 1`, entonces `1` más los siguientes 20 números pares es `1 + 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 10 + 12 + 14 + 16 + 18 + 20 + 22 + 24 + 26 + 28 + 30 + 32 + 34 + 36 + 38 + 40 = 421`.
- Si `num = 2`, entonces `2` más los siguientes 20 números pares es `2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 10 + 12 + 14 + 16 + 18 + 20 + 22 + 24 + 26 + 28 + 30 + 32 + 34 + 36 + 38 + 40 + 42 = 462`.

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo haría de esta manera. Sumando de a uno, pero reduciendo el número de pasos a la mitad, cambiando esto `j=numero+40` por esto `j=numero+20`.

Quedaría de esta manera.

```
for(int i=numero, j=numero+20;i<=j;i++)
{
    total_par+=2*i;
}
```

El `if` no debería existir ya que hace lo mismo en los dos casos... Es decir, si es par itero, y si no es par, también itero, cuando se puede decir, itero, pase lo que pase.

Nota: Me acabo de dar cuenta que el `if`, sí, debería existir, ya que si es verdadero, `int i=numero`, pero si es falso, `int i=numero+1`.

La siguiente línea...

```
for(int i=numero+1,j=numero+40;i<=j;i+2){
```

Se puede corregir de la siguiente manera (paso a paso):

```
for(int i=numero+1,j=numero+40;i<=j;i+=2){
for(int i=numero+1,j=numero+40;i<=j;i+=2){
for(int i=numero+0,j=numero+39;i<=j;i+=2){
for(int i=numero+0,j=numero+40;i< j;i+=2){
for(int i=numero+0,j=numero+20;i< j;i+=1){

for(int i=numero,j=numero+20;i<j;i++){
```

Comment: Gracias, lo he entendido y me ha sido útil. Pero no entiendo cuando dices "itero".

Comment: @MigHc iterar se refiere a hacer cada una de las repeticiones del bucle.

Comment: @Error404 bueno saberlo

Comment: @ArtEze por qué sumas `i` a `total_par` , si `i` no es par ya que aumenta de 1 en 1? o es que no me estoy percatando de algo

Comment: @Dev.Joel Buen detalle, no me di cuenta del error... Debería ser `total_par+=2*i`. Ya lo edité.

Comment: @MigHc Hice un detalle, puse "paso a paso" cómo corregir el for.

Answer (score 0):

Si bien ya esta la respuesta...

```
private Integer obtenerSuma(Integer intNumero, Integer intCantidadASumar) {
    Boolean intSeed = false;
    Integer  intResultado = 0;

    intSeed = (intNumero % 2)?2:1;

    for(Integer intIndex = 0; intIndex < intCantidadASumar; intIndex + intSeed) {
        intResultado += intNumero;
    }

    return intResultado;
}
```